# Trying to run Horizon with wine but get "DNGuard Runtime library not loaded!"

Tags: 20.04, wine

Basicaly just the title.
Also here's the full error I recive when I try to run it, right before the console closes:
[image]

Anyone know how I can fix this? Rather, how can I download this missing runtime library?
Am running Wine 9.0 in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: So I'm assuming no one knows how to fix this.